# How can I get the LEAST() value from a SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my query:

```
"UPDATE tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos tb1 LEFT JOIN 
tbl_pedidos_produtos tb2 ON tb1.produto_id = tb2.id SET 
tb1.status = CASE WHEN tb1.valor_total = 
SELECT LEAST(SELECT valor_total FROM tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos WHERE
produto_id = ".$produto->itens[$t]->pedido_id.") THEN 5 ELSE 4 WHERE pedido_id = ".$produto->itens[$t]->pedido_id
```

Error:

```
[19-Dec-2015 05:37:48 America/Sao_Paulo] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LEAST(SELECT valor_total FROM tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos WHERE produto' at line 1
```

Apparently I can't use LEAST() with a SELECT statement inside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) is expecting a number of arguments, and returns the smallest one of those.

What you are getting with your SELECT is however a result set, and therefore I think you are looking for [MIN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min). Exchange your LEAST() with this and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Not expert in mysql but you can use this code, to resolve this
`SELECT Least(valor_total) FROM tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos WHERE
produto_id = ".$produto->itens[$t]->pedido_id. "` instead explicit Least function on a select command :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function to find the smallest value across multiple rows.

`... total = (SELECT MIN(valor_total) FROM ...)`